# How in the Program send message to Forum Topic

Tags: python, pyrogram

I wanted to send a message to Forum Topic:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.raw import functions,types
app = Client("my_account", api_id="12345678", api_hash="g8u4h894urgh09eurhiugfdgfrgrg")
async def get_chat_themes(client):
    result = await app.invoke(
        functions.messages.SendMessage(peer =types.InputPeerChannel(channel_id=12345,access_hash=-1234),message ="Test",random_id =-1)
    )
    print(result)

with app:
    app.loop.run_until_complete(get_chat_themes(app))
```

This code sends a message to topic #General, how can I send it to another topic?
GetForumTopics outputs this:

```
{
    "_": "types.messages.ForumTopics",
    "count": 1,
    "topics": [
        {
            "_": "types.ForumTopic",
            "id": 12,
            "date": 1688764942,
            "title": "1",
            "icon_color": 16766590,
            "top_message": 12,
            "read_inbox_max_id": 13,
            "read_outbox_max_id": 0,
            "unread_count": 0,
            "unread_mentions_count": 0,
            "unread_reactions_count": 0,
            "from_id": {
                "_": "types.PeerUser",
                "user_id": 
            },
            "notify_settings": {
                "_": "types.PeerNotifySettings"
            },
            "my": true,
            "closed": false,
            "pinned": false,
            "short": false,
            "hidden": false
        },
        {
            "_": "types.ForumTopic",
            "id": 1,
            "date": 1688762115,
            "title": "General",
            "icon_color": 7322096,
            "top_message": 3,
            "read_inbox_max_id": 9,
            "read_outbox_max_id": 9,
            "unread_count": 0,
            "unread_mentions_count": 0,
            "unread_reactions_count": 0,
            "from_id": {
                "_": "types.PeerChannel",
                "channel_id": 
            },
            "notify_settings": {
                "_": "types.PeerNotifySettings"
            },
            "my": true,
            "closed": false,
            "pinned": false,
            "short": false,
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "messages": [
        {
            "_": "types.MessageService",
            "id": 12,
            "peer_id": {
                "_": "types.PeerChannel",
                "channel_id": 
            },
            "date": 1688764942,
            "action": {
                "_": "types.MessageActionTopicCreate",
                "title": "1",
                "icon_color": 16766590
            },
            "out": true,
            "mentioned": false,
            "media_unread": false,
            "silent": false,
            "post": false,
            "legacy": false,
            "from_id": {
                "_": "types.PeerUser",
                "user_id": 
            }
        },
        {
            "_": "types.MessageService",
            "id": 3,
            "peer_id": {
                "_": "types.PeerChannel",
                "channel_id": 
            },
            "date": 1688762477,
            "action": {
                "_": "types.MessageActionChatAddUser",
                "users": [
                    
                ]
            },
            "out": true,
            "mentioned": false,
            "media_unread": false,
            "silent": false,
            "post": false,
            "legacy": false,
            "from_id": {
                "_": "types.PeerUser",
                "user_id": 
            }
        }
    ],
    "chats": [
        {
            "_": "types.Channel",
            "id": ,
            "title": "",
            "photo": {
                "_": "types.ChatPhotoEmpty"
            },
            "date": 1688762115,
            "creator": true,
            "left": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "verified": false,
            "megagroup": true,
            "restricted": false,
            "signatures": false,
            "min": false,
            "scam": false,
            "has_link": false,
            "has_geo": false,
            "slowmode_enabled": false,
            "call_active": false,
            "call_not_empty": false,
            "fake": false,
            "gigagroup": false,
            "noforwards": false,
            "join_to_send": false,
            "join_request": false,
            "forum": true,
            "access_hash": -,
            "restriction_reason": [],
            "admin_rights": {
                "_": "types.ChatAdminRights",
                "change_info": true,
                "post_messages": true,
                "edit_messages": true,
                "delete_messages": true,
                "ban_users": true,
                "invite_users": true,
                "pin_messages": true,
                "add_admins": true,
                "anonymous": false,
                "manage_call": true,
                "other": true,
                "manage_topics": true
            },
            "default_banned_rights": {
                "_": "types.ChatBannedRights",
                "until_date": 2147483647,
                "view_messages": false,
                "send_messages": false,
                "send_media": false,
                "send_stickers": false,
                "send_gifs": false,
                "send_games": false,
                "send_inline": false,
                "embed_links": false,
                "send_polls": false,
                "change_info": false,
                "invite_users": false,
                "pin_messages": false,
                "manage_topics": false,
                "send_photos": false,
                "send_videos": false,
                "send_roundvideos": false,
                "send_audios": false,
                "send_voices": false,
                "send_docs": false,
                "send_plain": false
            },
            "usernames": []
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "_": "types.User",
            "id": ,
            "is_self": true,
            "contact": false,
            "mutual_contact": false,
            "deleted": false,
            "bot": false,
            "bot_chat_history": false,
            "bot_nochats": false,
            "verified": false,
            "restricted": false,
            "min": false,
            "bot_inline_geo": false,
            "support": false,
            "scam": false,
            "apply_min_photo": true,
            "fake": false,
            "bot_attach_menu": false,
            "premium": false,
            "attach_menu_enabled": false,
            "bot_can_edit": false,
            "access_hash": ,
            "first_name": "",
            "username": "",
            "phone": "",
            "status": {
                "_": "types.UserStatusOffline",
                "was_online": 
            },
            "restriction_reason": [],
            "usernames": []
        },
        {
            "_": "types.User",
            "id": ,
            "is_self": false,
            "contact": false,
            "mutual_contact": false,
            "deleted": false,
            "bot": true,
            "bot_chat_history": false,
            "bot_nochats": false,
            "verified": false,
            "restricted": false,
            "min": false,
            "bot_inline_geo": false,
            "support": false,
            "scam": false,
            "apply_min_photo": true,
            "fake": false,
            "bot_attach_menu": false,
            "premium": false,
            "attach_menu_enabled": false,
            "bot_can_edit": true,
            "access_hash": ,
            "first_name": "Test",
            "username": "Testrobot123_robot",
            "bot_info_version": 1,
            "restriction_reason": [],
            "usernames": []
        }
    ],
    "pts": 26,
    "order_by_create_date": false
}
```

I tried to find in the documentation how to send a message to the forum and found only functions.messages.SendMessage.
Maybe there is a solution to my problem using another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official Pyrogram documentation for the [messages.SendMessage](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/messages/send-message) API, you should use the `top_msg_id` parameter. Relevant excerpt from the docs (bolded for emphasis):

> top_msg_id (int 32-bit, optional) – **This field must contain the topic ID only when replying to messages in forum topics different from the “General” topic** (i.e. reply_to_msg_id is set and reply_to_msg_id != topicID and topicID != 1). If the replied-to message is deleted before the method finishes execution, the value in this field will be used to send the message to the correct topic, instead of the “General” topic.

Hope that helps.